# Using find and sed to copy 20th line of many files into one file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, find

I have a folder called `PKA1`

Within this folder I have several folders named as:

`1eV`, `2eV` .... `30eV`

Within each of these subfolders I have a file called `PKA.dump`

I want to copy the 20th line of `PKA.dump` in each subfolder to a file called `data.txt`.

I know I can use the find command to find all `PKA.dump` files as:

```
find . -type f -name PKA.dump
```

I also know I can write individually with `sed`:

```
sed -i '20q;d' PKA.dump > data.txt
```

But when I try to loop through all files and use `sed` such as:

```
find . -type f -name PKA.dump | sed -i '20q;d' PKA.dump > data.txt
```

I get this error:

```
sed: can't read PKA.dump: No such file or directory
```

Any help? I just want to sequentially have the 20th line from `PKA.dump` in file `1eV`, `2eV`, `3eV` etc in a file called `data.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name PKA.dump -type f -exec awk '
   FNR == 20 {print; nextfile}' {} +
```

`nextfile`, where available (GNU awk and some others like FreeBSD's and recent versions of `mawk` and [soon to be added to the standard](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607)) will skip to the next file. Where not, it will be ignored (it's just like dereferencing a `nextfile` variable); it will still work but read the files fully.

You can still do:

```
find . -name PKA.dump -type f -exec sed '20q;d' {} \;
```

But that means running one `sed` command per file which would be less efficient.

Comment: When I do: find . -name PKA.dump -type f -exec awk ' FNR == 20 {print; nextfile}' {} +nextfile  

I get an error find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @j you've got a spurious _nextfile_ next to your `+`

Comment: where is this file saved? I do not see it in directory?

Comment: @JacksonHart - it's not in your directory, you entered it in terminal at the end of your command (the command ends with a `+`, nothing should follow). Copy>paste the exact command in Stéphane's answer  and it will work.